# Отслеживание действий пользователя IOS

Tags: ios

Возможно ли вести трекинг того, в каких приложениях сидит пользователь в течение дня и сколько времени он проводит в каждом из них? Иными словами, возможно ли получить доступ к логу активности пользователя и передать на обработку приложению?

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя получить доступ к таким данным, ваше приложение запускается в отдельном [сендбоксе](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/) у которого есть ограниченый доступ к ситеме, и даже если вы найдете вариант использования системного api для получения таких данных то ваше приложение с вероятностью 99.9% не пройдет ревью.